# $N$ choose 2, with stipulation that each element could only be paired $k$ times (where $k < N$ )

Tags: probability, combinatorics

While I am relatively comfortable with the first part, I am unable to find a reliable way to calculate the second part with the stipulation stated.

For example, in it were `6 choose 2`, with the condition that each element could only be pared once, then the result would simply be `3`, where as if each element could only be paired twice, the result is `6`

**My ask:**

What I am looking for is a formula to calculate $N$ choose 2, given that each element could only be paired up with another element $k$ times, with no regard to order of the pairing.

To put concretely, supposed there are $N$ number of people in a room, and each person forms a pair with another person at random.  After a person has been paired with $k$ (where $k$ < $N$> random persons, she leaves the room and no longer participate in pairing.  How many pairs could it be formed given these conditions.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  It is not at all clear what question you are asking here.

Comment: I edited the question to make what I am asking more clear - thanks.

Comment: Please be clear whether you are counting the elements in some precise set (in which case you should be specific which set that is), or whether you are considering a problem of [extremal combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_combinatorics) here. My guess is that it is the latter, and that you are asking how large a subset of $\binom X2$ (where the set $X$ has $N$ elements) one can form so that no element $x\in X$ occurs in more than $k$ pairs of the subset.

Comment: With $N$ people, each of whom can participate in $k$ pairs, you can form $kN/2$ pairs. If both are odd, round down. Is this what you were after?

Comment: @Ross - this is correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $N$ people, each of whom can participate in $k$ pairs, you can have $kN/2$ pairs, assuming $k \le N$. If both $k,N$ are odd, round down.